# Arduino multiple Serial.find

Tags: arduino, timeout, find

I need a way for find two string in the serial, but I've read that it's impossible because the timeout of the Serial is about 1000ms so it can't receive the second string. Is there another way for find two string in the serial? I can only use Serial.find, not Serial.read because in the serial output there are many variable strings and I need only those two which are constant.

```
int porta = 7; 
int garage = 8;

void setup()
{
pinMode(porta, OUTPUT); 
 pinMode(garage, OUTPUT); 
Serial.begin(9600); 
Serial.flush();
digitalWrite(porta, HIGH);
digitalWrite(garage, HIGH);
}
void loop()
{


// Read any serial input
while (Serial.available() > 0)

if (Serial.find("garage"))
{
digitalWrite(garage, LOW);
delay(200);
  digitalWrite(garage, HIGH);
}
else if (Serial.find("porta"))
 {
digitalWrite(porta, LOW);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(porta, HIGH);
  }
delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.find()` is going to block in the first `if` until it times out, then block in the second `if` the same way.

Actually, looking at the Arduino source code shows that `Serial.find()` doesn't even work correctly in general; it won't find "babaa" in "bababaa", because it doesn't implement a state machine properly. (It will match up to the 4th character, then start over.)

You are going to have to read the bytes one at a time.

You could implement a state machine, which wouldn't be so bad because your target strings don't overlap.

An easier way might be to keep a buffer of that last 20 characters or so. When the buffer gets full, copy the last half to the first half and start filling the last half again. Check for the target strings with strstr() as each character arrives.

You might think doing something like checking for a 'g' or 'p' then checking for the rest of the target string would work, but it wouldn't. It would fail on "gporta".

For a state machine:

```
enum state {NONE, G, GA, GAR, GARA, GARAG, P, PO, POR, PORT};

enum state cur_state = NONE;
int porta = 7; 
int garage = 8;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(porta, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(garage, OUTPUT); 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Serial.flush();
    digitalWrite(porta, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(garage, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    // Read any serial input
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    (
        char c = Serial.read();

        switch(cur_state)
        {
        case G:
            if(c == 'a') cur_state = GA;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case GA:
            if(c == 'r') cur_state = GAR;
            else if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case GAR:
            if(c == 'a') cur_state = GARA;
            else if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case GARA:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = GARAG;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case GARAG:
            if(c == 'e')
            {
                  digitalWrite(garage, LOW);
                  delay(200);
                  digitalWrite(garage, HIGH);
                  cur_state = NONE;
            }
            else if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'a') cur_state = GA; /////// TRICKY!!
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case P:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else if(c == 'o') cur_state = PO;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case PO:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else if(c == 'r') cur_state = POR;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case POR:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else if(c == 't') cur_state = PORT;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        case PORT:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'a')
            {
                  digitalWrite(porta, LOW);
                  delay(200);
                  digitalWrite(porta, HIGH);
                  cur_state = NONE;
            }
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;

        default:
            if(c == 'g') cur_state = G;
            else if(c == 'p') cur_state = P;
            else cur_state = NONE;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```